# jquery return element to its original position

Tags: position, absolute

i'm trying to make a div expand upward on hover, then return to its original height on mouseout. Pretty simple. The div is positioned absolute, bottom: 0, so it clings to the bottom of its parent. The catch is that i don't have control over the length of the content in the div, so the top value is set to auto.

Therefore, i need to calculate the actual top position, then pass that value to the second function in hover(), which handles the mouseout animations, in order to restore its original height.

```
    $('#blog3 .blog-grid li').hover(
    function () { // mouse over
        // calculate .content-box top position
        var offset = $(this).find(".content-box").offset().top - $(this).find(".content-box").parent().offset().top;

        // darken the box
        $(this).find(".content-box").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)").animate({
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });

        // expand the content div
        $(this).find(".content-box").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: 0,
        }, {
            queue : false,
            duration : 500
        });

        $(this).find("p").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).find(".read-more").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 
    function () { // mouse out
        $(this).find(".content-box").css("background-color", "transparent").animate({
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });

        $(this).find(".content-box").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: offset + 'px', // <-- restore to original position
        }, {
            queue : false,
            duration : 500
        });

        $(this).find("p").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).find(".read-more").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
    }
);
```

The problem, of course, is that i can't pass the 'offset' variable to the second (mouseout) function, nor can i declare 'offset' as a global variable, because it needs to be calculated on hover.

i'm sure there must be another way to pass that number to the second function, but i can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question ;)

Set 'offset' as a global variable, then perform the position calculation inside the mouseover function.

```
var offset = null;
$('#blog3 .blog-grid li').hover(
    function () {
        //get .content-box top position
        offset = $(this).find(".content-box").offset().top - $(this).find(".content-box").parent().offset().top;

        // darken the box
        $(this).find(".content-box").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)").animate({
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });

        // initialize position
        $(this).find(".content-box").css("top", offset);

        // expand the content div
        $(this).find(".content-box").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: 0,
        }, {
            queue : false,
            duration : 500
        });

        $(this).find("p").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).find(".read-more").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find(".content-box").css("background-color", "transparent").animate({
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });

        $(this).find(".content-box").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: offset + 'px',
        }, {
            queue : false,
            duration : 500
        });

        $(this).find("p").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).find(".read-more").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
    }
);
```